# Simulating a SDE

Tags: numerical-methods, simulation

I have a question about simulating a SDE.

I want to simulate $dS=\alpha(K-S)dt+\sigma S dZ$ with use of a Euler-marayama scheme.
The numerical scheme becomes: $S_{i+1}=S_{i}+\alpha(K-S_{i})dt+\sigma S_{i}\sqrt{dt}Z$.

But now I want to know the condition for when this method is stable, because my solutions blow up.
I hope that anyone can help me out.

Comment: $P=S?~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: See P. Forsyth: An introduction to Computational Fincance ... https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~paforsyt/agon.pdf p. 34ff for the general numerical treatment of SDE, incl. using Brownian bridges for the refinement of solutions.